# Biasing using a Current Source in NMOS Common Source Amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I see that there are multiple ways to bias a simple Common Source NMOS transistor but I want to understand about biasing using current source.

I put up this circuit in SPICE:

[image]

The above is simple Common Source Amplifier biased with help of current source without a constant gate voltage. My first question is, "is this really biased with current source? or is it biased with -1.4V below the current source?"

I called this "biasing using current source" because changing the current value changes the operating point and Source potential is not fixed (while operation).

Well, now arises an interesting observation. I see that this circuit amplifies the voltage variations at Gate (which is what i wanted). 
However, the source potential varies with gate. (acts as source follower).
But to amplify, shouldn't the source potential be fixed? Only then Gate-Source potential would vary and produce the output right? So, I wanted to know how current variation happens across the resistor to amplify the signal? (shouldn't the current just stay constant?)

Comment: Neither, since there is no ground connection on the output side.

Comment: When you place a current source (I1) in series with a voltage source (V1) the alarm bells in your head should start ringing. Because one of the two will be obsolete. You can also add a ground so things make sense again.

Comment: "redundant" rather than "obsolete"?

Comment: Thanks. I believe its "redundant". So, I removed the voltage source but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: *but the behavior remains the same* Well obviously, since you just did "something" without understanding what you're doing. Your circuit **cannot work** since the right part of the circuit has no ground reference which is what Brian commented already.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, So, by "cannot work",  you mean it does not literally work or it cannot be analysed?  Well, The circuit works fine after removing the redundancy. Amplification happens just fine. I just wanted to know if this is can be called "current biasing" (operating point fixed by the current in the current source)  (the main question)

Comment: The problem with this circuit is that it has a floating part which has no resistive path to ground. The floating part is everything except V2 and the gate of the NMOS. On the negative side of V1 there should be a ground symbol to fix this. You're somehow **lucky** that the simulator has decided that the negative node of V1 is 0 Volt. There is no real reason why it should be 0 V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you measuring gain? You have to run AC analysis to measure gain. Also, connect the other end of the current source to ground.
 By the way, this circuit cannot have any gain at low frequencies because the current source acts as an AC open. Also, this is a biasing circuit and is not intended as a gain block.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.  So, this indeed is a biasing circuit.

Comment: My overall objective was to understand that if a differential amplifier is biased by a current source, why not a simple common source NMOS? The circuit became little wierd but biasing is accomplished by the value of the current in current source.

Comment: In differential amplifier, we are able to get gain (differential) because tail current node acts as a virtual ground. We do not get any degeneration for differential signals. As a first order estimate, the gain of the MOS circuit is given by ratio of impedance seen at the drain to that at source. Since we get open circuit for the current source load at the source, gain becomes zero.